# Is there a way to automatically "Rebase" an image in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose script that brings up a service

```
version : '2.0'
services:
        orig-db:
             image: web-url:{image_tag}
        custom-db:
             image: local_image: latest
```

Where image used in custom DB is the the result of bringing up a container with orig-db, performing some basic bash commands, and doing a docker commit. I want the custom-db image to always be the original image + these commands, even if the original image is updated. Is there a way to "rebase" off the original image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a Dockerfile as a simple form of a "rebase".

```
# Content of subdir/Dockerfile
FROM orig_image:latest

RUN some.sh
RUN basic.sh
RUN bash_commands.sh
```

When you build an image based on this file, it will always run the bash commands on top of the base image. Inside the compose file you can use the `build` property to instruct docker-compose to build the image instead of using a pre-made image.

```
version : '2.0'
services:
    orig-db:
         image: web-url:{image_tag}
    custom-db:
         build: somedir
```

If the base image changes, you need to tell docker-compose to rebuild the custom-db image again, running the bash commands again on top of the updated original image.

```
docker-compose up -d --build custom-db
```

Comment: What does "somedir" represent in the build property? Is that the subdirectory of the docker file?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. `somedir` is a new directory in which the Dockerfile is located. The name is arbitrary. I principle, you don't need to put the Dockerfile in a subdirectory, but in case you want to add more files, it's cleaner if you use a separate directory.